# How to float three divs right to left?

Tags: html, css

I think I understand basic left & right floats, but I cannot figure out this particular three-column layout. I'm not even sure what I want is possible. I want to create a single row with three <div> columns as follows:

1. The rightmost <div> touches the right edge of the container,
   contains nowrap text, and is as wide as necessary.
2. The center <div> is immediately to the left of the rightmost
   <div>, contains an <img>, and is as wide as necessary.
3. The leftmost <div> touches the left edge of the container,
   contains word-wrapped text, and uses a minimum width of say 20% but
   dynamically stretches to use whatever remaining width is available
   in the container.
4. A horizontal scrollbar should appear if (and only if) the sum of the
   widths of the three columns is greater than the width of the
   container. I don't want any of these <div>s moving down to the
   next row.

I'm having trouble with #3 & #4. Is this possible? I'm guessing I need the leftmost column to actually be two <div>s (one directly on top of the other), one empty <div> with 20% width above/under the other wrapped text <div> with unspecified width, but I can't figure out how to do that.



Thanks,
Tom.III

Comment: Unless you want to use table-design layout I think you need to look at Html 5 Flexbox. See here for example -> http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. (Since you have rules of min 20% fill width and so forth)

Answer (score 1):

```
        <style>
            #main{
                position: fixed;
                top: 0; 
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #left{
                float: left;
                max-width: 32%;
                width: auto;
                margin-right: 3px;
                background-color: red;
            }
            #center{
                float: left;
                max-width: 32%;
                width: auto;
                margin-right: 3px;
                margin-left: 3px;
                background-color: green;
            }
            #right{
                float: right;
                max-width: 32%;
                width: auto;
                min-width: 20%;
                background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="main">
            This is the main div!
                <div id="left">
                    Hello From The Left!
                </div>
                <div id="center">
                    Hello From The Center!
                </div>
                <div id="right">
                    Hello From The Center!
                </div>
        </div>
```